# Activity instance changing per tick in JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, android-activity, java-native-interface

I have an Android lifecycle question that I can't find answered anywhere else.

(This is not a question about making the activity class a global ref)

I'm using the standard JNI->Native Init() and Tick() calls to run the game on the native side. Very similar to the San Angeles demo.

I pass both of these calls a instance of the Java Activity object. This is so I can call back
to Java in order to (for example, turn adverts off, interact with the Java Twitter, etc).

Q1 : When I call Tick() to call my native calls, does this create a new thread, if so, why don't I have to call DetachCurrentThread from the native side?

Q2: I've tried caching the Activity instance on my Native Init() function and storing this in a static. This works on some devices, but on pre-android 5.0 device I get a stale reference JNI error when I use the instance in the Tick() function. Will making this a global 'reference' like I do for the activity 'class' in my OnLoad() function sort this?

Q3: When the user closes the interstitial adverts, I get a callback on the Java side, which I pass to the native side (eg, to restart the music). Does this create a new Native thread? Will my previously cached Activity instance still be valid?

Many thanks,

Steve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found my own answers.

1.No.
2.Yes, do the GlobalReference thing.
3.No, but the the Java side a a new thread.